# Asked to simulate CMOS N_Type and P_Type transistors. No Idea

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I first want to apologize as this is a very specific question that may not help anyone else.

Anyways, I was asked:

"Overview
Write simulations of the CMOS N_Type and P_Type transistors. Use your simulated transistors to implement the common logic gates."

I have read about transistors online and even tried finding these specific ones but I can't find any concrete answers. If I just knew what the **heck** this guy wants me to do I would be really grateful.

I was given a BinaryDigit class and an abstract Transistor class. I am to extend the Transistor and create non-abstract N-Type and P_type transistors with isOpen() and isClosed() methods.

Lastly, I have to create a LogicGate(implement and/or/etc) class using the two transistors.

Anyone know what I should do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a shot in the dark here, but this is what came to mind. The PMOS class would be identical, except you'd check for `b.digit == 0` instead.

```
class NMOS extends Transistor
{
    boolean open;

    public NMOS(BinaryDigit b)
    {
        open = b.digit == 1;
    }

    public void setInput(BinaryDigit b)
    {
        open = b.digit == 1;
    }

    public boolean isOpen()
    {
        return open;
    }

    public boolean isClosed()
    {
        return !open;
    }
}
```

I suggest that you read up on CMOS implementations of logic gates. Here's an AND gate, as an example.

```
class AndGate
{
    NMOS t1, t2;
    public AndGate()
    {
        t1 = new NMOS(new BinaryDigit(0));
        t2 = new NMOS(new BinaryDigit(0));
    }

    public BinaryDigit map(BinaryDigit input1, BinaryDigit input2)
    {
        t1.setInput(input1);
        t2.setInput(input2);

        return new BinaryDigit(((t1.isOpen() && t2.isOpen()) ? (1) : (0));
    }
}
```